# Azure Mobile Services .NET Client with Custom Authentication Missing X-ZUMO-AUTH Header and Failing API Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have the following scenario:

1) Azure Mobile Services API
2) Custom Authentication
3) Web and Xamarin Clients
4) Small test harness (.NET app using MSTest)

With the custom authentication, I can login from both the browser and the unit test and get back the appropriate userID and token.

Something like this:

```
  var user = await Connect.MobileClient
            .InvokeApiAsync<LoginRequest, MobileServiceUser>(
            "CustomLogin", new LoginRequest()
            {
                username = username,
                password = password
            });
```

I then do the following:

```
Connect.MobileClient.CurrentUser = user;
```

Debugging makes it clear that the userId and the MobileServicesAuthenticationToken are correctly set.

When, I invoke the POST on my controller, however, I'm getting tossed out with unauthorized after the Initialize method on the controller executes.

A few notes:

1) Everything works swimmingly if I do the POST from the "try this out" (after registering, logging in, and pasting the token value in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header).
2) Likewise, no issue if I remove the
    [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
from the controller class or method (tried both).

Here is the failing post (from Fiddler):

```
POST https://anapi.azure-mobile.net/tables/Organization__systemproperties=__createdAt%2C__updatedAt%2C__version%2C__deleted HTTP/1.1
X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: dfddf760-ecef-49cb-8197-2faaaaa11502
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: aaaaaauJOUyfFjjPmZpobTybtaaaaaa
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200;     arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200;     arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.30324.0)
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: anapi.azure-mobile.net
Content-Length: 110
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"OrganizationId":0,"Name":"International Bozo, Inc.","Address":"Dallas, Texas","Accounts":null,"Courses":null}
```

The "try this" HTTP POST includes the X-ZUMO-AUTH header with the appropriate token.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the client.currentUser property before calling the client.invokeAPI method (it appears from your question you are doing the other order)

The X-ZUMO-AUTH header is then populated from the user.MobileAuthenticationToken
as shown here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Http/MobileServiceHttpClient.cs#L566-L569

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had the order correct.  The issue is resolved now, though I don't know precisely what solved it.  It may have been a certificate issue running the debugger with fiddler in the middle.

Comment: For sure fiddler breaks the things for you. But you can set the certificate in the settings.